# Vue not passing events to child

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

When in raw HTML/CSS/JS, we had scrolling working in child elements, sticky headers, and swiping to delete. However, after initializing Vue on the parent div element, all of the functionality was immediately lost. Only the parent div scrolls, and only click events are fired (header is no longer sticky, swiping is no longer even registered by child elements).

Is there a way to have Vue either pass the event through the parent or make Vue unable to overwrite our custom animations?

How I use Vue in `index.js`:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    mounted() {
        window.onscroll = function () {
            myFunction()
        }
        swipeable()
    },
    data: {
        e: []
    },
    methods: {
        refresh: function () {
          e = ... mutate e like this ...
        }
    },
    updated: function () {
        this.$nextTick(function () {
            console.log("Update finished.")
            swipeable()
        })
    }
})
```

The functions called just apply some basic jQuery and Hammer listeners to different elements.

The HTML is constructed like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Aiko</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <div class="top-container">
        ... raw html ...
    </div>

    <ul class="messages" id="root">
        <li v-for="el in e">
            <div class="message">
                <h3>{{el.header.title}}</h3>
          <div class="messages-bottom">
              ... raw html ...
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="button-delete">Delete</button>
      </li>
    </ul>


    <div class="footer">
        ... raw html ...
    </div>


    <script src='https://hammerjs.github.io/dist/hammer.min.js '></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To communicate from parent to child you have to use the attributes properties not events, the events is for communication between the child and the parent

Comment: Props down ↓, events up ↑

Comment: Our customization is mostly Hammer and jQuery, and also just scrolling. The parent element scrolls but the child elements do not. The Hammer events we set up are not firing but are completely separate from Vue (they are not tied to any Vue events)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the initialization of your custom plugins, event listeners, etc in the `mounted()` method of your root component.

for example:

```
<template>
    <div ref="sampleElement">Target Element</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted: function() {
            $(this.$refs.sampleElement).myPlugin();
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: We don't initialize any plugins though, they're imported via JS CDN and are called (e.g. jquery and hammer). I tried calling the jQuery and Hammer functions through Vue as well to no avail--it seems the events are just not firing

Comment: You are not using any module bundler like webpack?

Comment: No, this is a very simple use of Vue, just for v-for to dynamically render a list. We include it via script tag

Comment: Can you show some code so we can take a look and analyze?

Comment: No problem, added some snippets to the question

Comment: Thanks, but your snippet doesn't actually show the current structure of your html code.

Comment: If you are only using vue on a specific part of your code, your vue instance doesn't need to be attacched to the root element. You can attach it to specific container element which contains your list that uses vue.

Comment: I have added our full HTML but our extent of Vue is really that small. I tried attaching it just to the <ul> element shown which fixed the scrolling but still did not solve the issues with the other events (swipes) not firing in the <li> tags.

Comment: It has something to do with vuejs's rendering functionality, the problem here is it could be that the events we're deleted when vue re-renders the view. So you need to re-initialize those events that we're lost everytime it re-renders the list.

May I ask what swipe library you are using? have you already checked their documentation regarding re-initializing the functionalities?